# Why Oracle displays ??? for special characters like åäö

Tags: oracle, nls-lang

Some time ago my PL/SQL stopped showing characters `åäö`.

I've tried reinstalling oracle_home_11g, PL/SQL cleaned the registry but the problem remains.

[image: picture1]
[image: picture2]

Anyone know why?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your client settings. You probably need to set correct NLS_LANG parameter on the system.

Comment: Already checked and they are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably it is due to the mismatch between the **locale-specific NLS characterset** and the **database characterset**. Or else, the **NLS_LANG** value is not correctly set in the **OS environmental variable**.

Have a look at [Why are junk values/special characters/question marks displayed on my client?](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/09/24/why-are-junk-values-displayed-in-my-client/)

1. Your client charaterset doesn't match with database characterset.

You can compare between :

```
-- locale-specific characterset

select value
from   v$nls_parameters 
where  parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';


-- database characterset

select value
from   nls_database_parameters 
where  parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

If you see a mismatch between the two, then set the locale-specific NLS characterset to that of database characterset.

2. If the above charactersets match, then you need to set the NLS_LANG value in the OS environmental variable.

For Windows OS, the format is:

```
[NLS_LANGUAGE]_[NLS_TERRITORY].[NLS_CHARACTERSET]
```

Follow the instruction in the documentation regarding setting up the NLS_LANG : [Setting the NLS_LANG Environment Variable for Oracle Databases](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12102_01/books/AnyInstAdm784/AnyInstAdmPreInstall18.html)

Comment: select value
from v$nls_parameters
UNION ALL
select value
from nls_database_parameters: 1 SWEDISH
2 SWEDEN
3 Kr
4 SWEDEN
5 ,.
6 GREGORIAN
7 RRRR-MM-DD
8 SWEDISH
9 WE8MSWIN1252
10 SWEDISH
11 HH24:MI:SSXFF
12 RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSXFF
13 HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR
14 RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR
15 €
16 AL16UTF16
17 BINARY
18 BYTE
19 FALSE
20 AMERICAN
21 AMERICA
22 $
23 AMERICA
24 .,
25 WE8MSWIN1252
26 GREGORIAN
27 DD-MON-RR
28 AMERICAN
29 BINARY
30 HH.MI.SSXFF AM
31 DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
32 HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
33 DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
34 $
35 BINARY
36 CHAR
37 FALSE
38 AL16UTF16
39 11.2.0.3.0

Comment: That is wrong, have a look at this [NLS_LANG FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html#_Toc110410549) where is says: "B) `SELECT * from v$nls_parameters;`
This view shows the current session parameters and the **DATABASE** characterset as seen in the NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS view." and "**The <clients characterset> part of NLS_LANG is NOT shown in any system table or view.**"

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I didn't get you. You are reiterating the same thing, as the answer and the FAQ. What's wrong? Where did I say that NLS_LANG value could be seen in v$ view? The former is at database level, and the latter is at OS level.

Comment: You write *You can compare between: -- locale-specific characterset select ... from v$nls_parameters; -- database characterset select ... from nls_database_parameters ... if you see mismatch...*. This imply these values could be different. However, according NLS_LANG FAQ both queries show the database character set and thus they can never be different.

Comment: Not helping.... Both shows the same value. NLS_LANG is properly set on my Windows ; in registry. I even tried to set environment variable before launching SQLPlus but same result... I think your answer is not accurate