# Oracle SQL find character ¡ in data

Tags: sql, oracle, encoding

Is it possible to find this underscore i ¡ character in database records? If I do like this

```
select * from mytable where cell like '%¡%';
```

it founds rows, where ? is present, not ¡. But this ? is wrong character in those words so maybe there are encoding problems. I think encoding is WIN1257

Comment: Column cell data type?

Comment: @jarlh column type is VARCHAR2 (4000 Byte)

Comment: I have a suspicion that the tool you use cannot handle UTF8 chars, and shows you this "?" instead as select result. To verify, just search for a record that surely has your special character in it, and see how it shows up in your SQL client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
select * from mytable where instr(cell, UNISTR(<UNICODE code of your character>))>0;
```

example:

```
create table mytable(
  cell varchar2(100)
);

insert into mytable values('normal string');
insert into mytable values('fünny string');
commit;

select * from mytable where instr(cell, UNISTR('\00fc'))>0;
```

Output:

```
CELL
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fünny string

1 row selected.
```

Edited: like @Wernfried Domscheit recommended i've changed CHR --> UNISTR,  - indeed this should work with any character set

Comment: This works only if your database character set is `AL32UTF8` (or similar). Better use `WHERE INSTR(cell, UNISTR('\00fc') ) > 0` (resp. `UNISTR('\00a1')` for "¡"), then you are independent on that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL*Plus you have to set your code page and your `NLS_LANG` value accordingly.

```
C:\>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

C:\>set NLS_LANG=.WE8MSWIN1252
C:\>sqlplus ...

SQL> select * from mytable where cell like '%¡%';
```

Note, Windows **Codepage1257 does not have character "¡"**.
You must change the code page to `chcp 1252` or `chcp 28591` for ISO-8859-1 for instance.